# How can I get my Account ID on Backblaze B2?

Tags: account-management

I'm trying out Backblaze B2. In order to use the `b2` command line tool, I'm following the quick start directions at [Create An Account](https://www.backblaze.com/b2/docs/quick_account.html). This page says:

> This page displays the account ID that you'll need to access your account. Make a note of it while you're here.

but I can't see anything resembling an "account ID" on my page. (Yes, I have enabled the "B2 Cloud Storage" and have used the web interface to create buckets and upload files.) The example account page shown on the quick start page also doesn't show anything like an account ID. Where can I find my account ID and application key?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to your Application Keys (https://secure.backblaze.com/app_keys.htm). Use the `keyId`:

[image: Application Keys]

> NOTE: The terminology for the Master Application Key ID was recently changed from being called the Account ID. If you are using an integration where the terminology has not been updated to reflect our change, the Master Application Key ID will work in place of the Account ID. For a non-master app key that has been created, you can use that key's keyID in place of an Account ID.

Source: https://help.backblaze.com/hc/en-us/articles/360022330274-Locating-the-Master-Application-Key-and-Master-Application-Key-ID-Pair

Comment: Note that you can create a new App Key (with the button at the bottom of the page as seen on the screenshot) with read/write/read+write permission to all or to a specific bucket. You don't have to use the Master App Key, and frankly you shouldn't.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to go here:
https://secure.backblaze.com/b2_buckets.htm

then you'll see the link to "Show Account ID and Application Key"

Comment: This answer is no longer helpful. The page referenced no longer has such a link

Answer (score 0):

These answers are wrong -- you need to add a new key (NOT the master key).
It then provides a keyId

https://www.backblaze.com/blog/how-to-connect-your-synology-nas-to-backblaze-b2-cloud-storage/